# Spring boot to include dependency of another springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have created a springboot to keep all common code. I am adding this jar in other springboot applications [in the pom file]. Build works well but I am going mad in deploying the war file in the jboss. I have moved all project dependencies to common pom file, I get below error when deploying the war into jboss :

org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'insuredObjectDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2:

**SpringBoot A pom file is :**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>CommonLayer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

**SpringBoot B pom file is :**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>CommonLayer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependency>all dependency for the project</dependency>
```

It seems that both application is creating the entity manager but I am not able to understand why and how to stop it. When I start the application as boot, it starts successfully and application works fine.

Comment: AFAIK using an artifact with `spring-boot-starter-parent` as dependency causes problems.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the spring-boot-starter-parent and now the error is gone. But still I get some conflict between tomcat and jboss server. When I deploy the war and start the jboss server I get : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer

Comment: Issue is resolved. I had to exclude the tomcat from both the application.